# How can I send "SendMessage" from a keyboard/macropad?

Tags: windows, wm-syscommand

Ok, I'll try to make this somewhat coherent, as I am not the best writer.

I have an AHK script which uses SendMessage command to send code 0x112, 0xf170, 2 to call WM_SYSCOMMAND which responds to SC_MONITORPOWER and 2 is the Power off function. This results in my monitor going to sleep, which is nice. However, as this is an AHK script, it requires actual buttons to be pressed, buttons like "a" "s" "d" and such. What I am looking for is how could I reprogram a button or two from arduino Leonardo to send that code directly, and put the monitors to sleep.

I am not a coder, and can pretty much only edit code in its simplest form.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to turn off the monitor then you can use [`nircmd.exe monitor off`](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html). This tool also supports sendmsg and postmsg commands.

Regarding AHK, the [auto-execute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto) runs without a hotkey.

[This](https://github.com/sebinside/HotkeylessAHK) web controlled AHK solution might also be of interest to you...

Comment: Hi! Thanks, these definitely help!


I'm also looking for a keyboard command which could do the same regardless of what has been instaleld on the PC. Additionally, I was thinking about getting a QMK keypad (haven't used one yet) and thinking if I could do the same thing with it somehow.

(Tried upvoting you but apparently my reputation is not high enough to do so)